# How to derive the formula for total impedance, $Z$, in an $RLC$ circuit?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, capacitance, inductance

Where this is an AC circuit, how can we derive the below formula for impedance, $Z$?

$R = $ resistance, $X_{L} = $ inductive reactance, and $X_{c} = $ capacitive reactance.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The impedance is actually a complex quantity. It has a magnitude which describes the ratio between current and voltage magnitude, but also a phase which gives the phase difference between the current and the voltage. So $|U|=|Z|\cdot|I|$ and $Phase(U) - Phase(I) = Phase(Z)$.

For a resistor, the impedance is equal to the resistance $Z_R = R$ because there is no phase difference between the current and the voltage.

For a capacitor $Z_C = \frac{1}{j \cdot \omega C}$, with $j \cdot j = -1$. It is imaginary because the phase of the current is 90 degree greater than the phase of the voltage for capacitors.

For an inductance $Z_L = j \cdot \omega L$. It is imaginary because the phase of the current is 90 degree less than the phase of the voltage.

Impedances are really nice to work with, because you can apply the same rules as you do for resistors when putting several impedances in series or in parallel.

So if all impedances are in series, like in your picture, then the total impedance is simply $$Z_{tot} = Z_R+Z_C+Z_L = R + \frac{1}{j \cdot \omega C} + j \cdot \omega L$$

If the impedances were in parallel you would have $$\frac{1}{Z_{tot}} = \frac{1}{Z_R}+ \frac{1}{Z_C}+\frac{1}{Z_L}$$

The formula you showed in your question is not really a formula for the impedance. It is a formula for the absolute value of the impedance. In other words, in your formula you have $$Z = |Z_{tot}| = \sqrt{\Re(Z_{tot})^2 + \Im(Z_{tot})^2}$$

For $Z_{tot} = Z_R+Z_C+Z_L = R + \frac{1}{j \cdot \omega C} + j \cdot \omega L$, the real part is $\Re(Z_{tot})=R$ and the imaginary part is $\Im(Z_{tot})=\omega L - \frac{1}{\omega C}$. So if we define $X_L = \omega L$ and $X_C = \frac{1}{\omega C}$ we get :

$$Z = |Z_{tot}| = \sqrt{\Re(Z_{tot})^2 + \Im(Z_{tot})^2} = \sqrt{R^2 +(\omega L - \frac{1}{\omega C})^2} = \sqrt{R^2 + (X_L-X_C)^2}$$

This $Z$ give you an idea of the ratio of the magnitudes of the current and the voltage, but gives no information about the phase. I guess that if you are using it you don't know much about complex numbers and why they are useful to describe the magnitude and phase of oscillating quantities. But trying to avoid them makes your life only more difficult, so I suggest you to learn some basics about complex numbers and understand where the Euler formula comes from.

I also suggest you to watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P9xSEhPENqM) video to understand what I mean by "the phase of the current is 90 degree greater than the phase of the voltage in a capacitor".

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yvzyC4VBpUU) is a small video to understand how to take the absolute value of a complex number, so you understand where the square root comes from. Also notice that when taking the imaginary part of $Z_{tot}$ I used the fact that $\frac{1}{j} = -j$.

Comment: The video you sent really helped. But the term R(Ztot)² and j(Ztot)² made the explanation above confusing at the end.

Comment: See that last paragraph I added, it should explain you why we took Re(Ztot)^2 + Im(Ztot)^2 has absolute value square of Ztot

Comment: But how did you get j(Ztot)=wL – 1/wc

Comment: since $1/j = -j$ you can write $\frac{1}{j \cdot \omega C} + j \cdot \omega L =\frac{-j}{ \omega C} + j \cdot \omega L = j (\frac{-1}{ \omega C} +  \omega L) $. The imaginary part of that is the term without a j so $\frac{-1}{ \omega C} +  \omega L$

Comment: Okay. That approach didn't come to my mind. Thanks 